# How to add a timestamp field using Composite C1?

Tags: c1-cms

How can I add `ChangeDate` field to a global datatype in data perspective? I can add `CreateDate` field easily but stuck at record modification time.

This is how I add CreateDate field:

- Just add a new field and rename it as CreateDate, type is Date

[image: 2014-04-26 00-52-36 C1 localhost - Google Chrome.png]

- In the advanced tab; remove widget and set default value as function Now.

[image: 2014-04-26 00-54-03 Ekran görüntüsü.png]

Can I add another field which one keeps the modification date automatically, if any?

Comment: You'll have to add a little more detail if you want anybody to have a clue what you're talking about. Add a `ChangeDate` field to what?

Comment: @JimMischel A nicer tone would be simply to suggest the OP add "Composite C1" to the title. The question is tagged with 'Composite-c1" and that is what the screen shots are. There are plenty of Composite-C1 questions in the forum.

Comment: @NimeCloud  I'm not sure why you have a 'C#' tag. That is probably why the other users will react negatively to your question. I suggest you remove the C# tag and change the question title to something like __How do I add a timestamp field using Composite C1__

Comment: I've added "Composite C1:" at the beginning, however the title has been modified by 3 people's votes... And yes, it was easy question for C1 people. I've also added c# tag because of C1 and C# are bonded together.

Comment: On hold? Not clear? lol I think you don't know what Composite is, that's clear.

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?cb=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [burningice](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/burningice)

There is a package for it here which you can use to enable ChangeHistory on dynamic types https://bitbucket.org/burningice/compositec1contrib/src/8f53d846304f4dea942b9169481ea3e53580804e/ChangeHistory/?at=default

For static types, just make sure to inherit the Composite.Core.Types.IChangeHistory interface.
[Read the full discussion online.](http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/543248#post1238449)

Answer (score 1):

I think event tracking of data addition and updating gives you a solution to add modified date.

You can even remove this modified date field from Mark up. But this will be in DB.

The five events that can be tracked in composite c1 data types are

1. OnAfterAdd
2. OnAfterUpdate
3. OnDeleted
4. OnBeforeAdd
5. OnBeforeUpdate

More information on data addition on the [following link](http://vishnunadesh.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/how-to-do-an-event-on-adding-data-to-a-data-type/).