# Access Abstract Syntax Tree in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, abstract-syntax-tree, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to implement an extension for Visual Studio 2013 (using C#) for C++ programmers, in which the user could right click on any variable in his/her C++ code and I would give him all sorts of information on that variable (like usages or which function is it passed to ... etc.).

Do you know how can I achieve this ? If so - can I get the C++ syntax tree ?

Thanks

PS Any open source project I could use as a reference ?

Comment: I don't think you can.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957350/is-the-vc-code-dom-accessible-from-vs-addons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this will solve your problem, but you might try to use the PDB file (Program database), which contains among other global variables, local variables, function names and the addresses of their entry points, [etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Further info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eee38t3h.aspx), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370hs6k4.aspx), and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/108e9y6d.aspx).

There is also a [tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P) available to Inspect the Content of a Program Database (PDB) File.
Further useful info to read is provided [here](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know).